# Post to Facebook on behalf of my web application users - Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, facebook, authentication, post

I have created a web application and I would like users to be able to log into their own Facebook account to publish posts on their Facebook profile from my web application.
Every time I connect them to Facebook with authentication, I get back a token that does not retain the requested permissions, especially "write to profile".

I am on Laravel.
I have tested with PHP SDKs, with Socialithe and even with PostMan. I can't find the solution.

Do you know if this is possible? And how?

Thanks

Comment: You mean the users should be able to share your website content on facebook?

Comment: there is no permission to write to a personal profile anymore. you must use the official share dialogs for that. there is no need to authenticate users.

Comment: Thanks ! And do you know if it is possible on Instagram as it is the same API ?